# Sharepoint 2013 Discussion reply Emails sent with default url

Tags: email, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 web application based on ADFS authentication with two URLs: the default one, used only internally, and the Intranet one, where users connect.

On community sites, when someone replies a topic, the user that created that topic receives an email informing that he has answers.
This email contains links to see the answer, the full conversations etc... 
The problem is this links point to my default URL, so users cannot follow to the answers.

Is there some way to configure or customize these emails?

I've been able to customize the URL alerts point to in Central Admin (System Settings-> Cross Firewall Access Zone ), but I don't know if there's some way to do something similar with these emails.

I cannot switch between my Default URL and the other one.